# Convert VB's Val to Java?

Tags: java, vb6

How to implement VB's Val() function using Java programming language or is there any API that has the same method?

Answer (score 7):

You should use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [`Float.parseFloat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html), [`Double.parseDouble`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) etc - or a [`NumberFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instead, depending on whether you want to treat the input in a culture-sensitive manner or not.

EDIT: Note that these expect the string to contain the number and nothing else. If you want to be able to parse strings which might start with a number and then contain other bits, you'll need to clean the string up first, e.g. using a regular expression.

Comment: Those don't do the same thing that Val does. Unlike val, they expect clean strings.

Comment: basically I've "implemented" this answer, without the regular expression

Answer (score 4):

If my Google skills serve me, `Val()` converts a string to a number; is that correct?

If so, [`Integer.parseInt(myString)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) or [`Double.parseDouble(myString)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) are the closest Java equivalents. However, any invalid character causes them to treat the entire string as invalid; you can't parse, say, street numbers from an address with them.

**Edit:** Here is a method that is a closer equivalent:

```
public static double val(String str) {
    StringBuilder validStr = new StringBuilder();
    boolean seenDot = false;   // when this is true, dots are not allowed
    boolean seenDigit = false; // when this is true, signs are not allowed
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '.' && !seenDot) {
            seenDot = true;
            validStr.append(c);
        } else if ((c == '-' || c == '+') && !seenDigit) {
            validStr.append(c);
        } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            seenDigit = true;
            validStr.append(c);
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            // just skip over whitespace
            continue;
        } else {
            // invalid character
            break;
        }
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(validStr.toString());
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(val(" 1615 198th Street N.E."));
    System.out.println(val("2457"));
    System.out.println(val(" 2 45 7"));
    System.out.println(val("24 and 57"));
}
```

Output:

```
1615198.0
2457.0
2457.0
24.0
```

I can't vouch for its speed, but it is likely that `Double.parseDouble` is the most expensive part. I suppose it might be a little faster to do the double parsing in this function also, but I would have be certain that this is a bottleneck first. Otherwise, it's just not worth the trouble.

Comment: It converts to Double. But I'm not sure how that maps in the Java type system.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Number Val(String value) {
    try {
        return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is not a number");
    }
}


Number a = Val("10");     // a instanceof Long 
Number b = Val("1.32");   // b instanceof Double
Number c = Val("0x100");  // c instanceof Long
```

Comment: Val will take the string "123 LakeView Dr." and return the nmber 123. Parse will not.

Comment: you can simply ad a regular expression to strip non-numeric part.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValResult = Val(" 1615 198th Street N.E.") ' ValResult is set to 1615198
ValResult = Val("2457")                    ' ValResult is set to 2457.
ValResult = Val(" 2 45 7")                 ' ValResult is set to 2457.
ValResult = Val("24 and 57")               ' ValResult is set to 24.
```

any Java API can make the same behavior?

Comment: You'd probably want to use a regex to just remove any non-digits (possibly allowing . and - if you want non-integers and negative numbers... remember to escape the . though!)

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = parseFloat("0" + /\d*\.?\d*/.exec(value))
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm

Answer (score -2):

If you want to convert a string to an integer use:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(aString);
```