# How to do Excel's "Convert to Number" in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading data from Excel using Apache POI. I want to convert some cells to number while reading in Java as following:

```
Input 01.0234500
Output 1.02345

Input 412206362371
Output 4.12206E+11 

Input 1234.201400002345
Output 1234.2014
```

When I am using "Convert to Number" in Excel, it works fine. But I want the same output while reading Excel cells in Java.

[image]

It can also be achieved using `=VALUE()` function in Excel. But how do I implement the same functionality in Java?

Comment: You get a string and have to use DecimalFormat, to fromat convert to number.

Comment: @anupganatra can you be more clear what data is in excel, whar you are getting through Java, and waht finall you want

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have input data as I have shown in screenshot and when I apply =VALUE() function then I get output as I have mentioned above. Now I just want equivalent function of =VALUE() of excel in Java.

Comment: Is [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852639/convert-vbs-val-to-java) what you are looking for?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It doesn't give exact output as I have mentioned above. Please read my question with input and output.

Comment: Sorry I don't work with java. Just dropped in to point you towards that link :)

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a number of ways to accomplish what you stipulate, but the most direct method is just to use the `VALUE()` function and then evaluate it.  This certainly is not the most efficient method, but it works.

Essentially we just read in the value of the input cell, then create a new cell formula cell which contains the `VALUE()` function with the original value as the parameter.  After that we call `evalutateInCell` to evaluate the `VALUE()` function and replace the cell value with the results.

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("test");

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell inCell = row.createCell(0);            
        inCell.setCellValue("01.0234500");
        Cell outCell = row.createCell(1);

        FormulaEvaluator fev = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        String value = inCell.getStringCellValue();            
        outCell.setCellFormula("VALUE(" + value + ")");
        fev.evaluateInCell(outCell);
```

You can use the same method to replace the contents of the original cell if that is your preference.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It works perfectly fine when you want to write in excel sheet. But in my case, I am reading the excel sheet and I want output in any variable in Java. evaluateInCell() can be used if you want to write output in excel cell with formula applied.

Comment: Are you trying to get Strings which are formatted as the above numbers?  Or the above numbers in `double` form?

Comment: Above code will write in excel cell by applying the formula. But what I want is to get the output in some variable in Java with =VALUE() function applied. I don't wont to write in excel file. Also when I am trying to get output in some variable then it doesn't give me exact output as we get while writing in excel.

Comment: You can go an additional step and use `.setCellType(CellType.STRING.ordinal())` and then `.getStringCellValue()` to read the `String` value of the cell.  I am not sure what the use of that would be, but it should format it as the `General` format in Excel would.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString()
```